# JList Wiping out previous enteries from a new List

Tags: java, swing, action, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I wrote a program on moving data from one list to another using JList. But when I move the selected data from one list to another, the previous enteries in the list to which I moving data gets overwritten by the new data.

How can I make program in which the previous enteries I made in a list doesn't get overwritten by the new data which I try to move?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever adding an element to the list, you should add it to the list model using methods like `addElement()`.

Don't add data to the `JList` using `setData()` or similar methods.

```
DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();
JList list = new JList(model);
model.addElement(someElement);
```

Comment: I amn't able to find any method called addElement for JList

Comment: Sorry. can you please put some syntax cuz I am learning Java gui and not familiar with alot of methods

Comment: What are the purposes of DefaultListModel besides adding data at the end of JList

Comment: It helps you implementing the MVC (Model-View-Controller) pattern.

Comment: You mean it works like Linked List and by default puts data at the end of the list to which I have passed its object

Answer (score 2):

You should use a `DefaultListModel` as the JList model, and add and remove from there.